# Image optimization for OCR

Tags: image, ocr, tesseract

I'm using tesseract v 3.02

I have the following image [image: Tesseract Image]

[Download Image (right click -- save link as)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eg7EF.png)

I would like to get the text from it. I'm using tesseract for the purpose.

When writing this command:

```
tesseract cropped.png tess -psm 7
```

The result I get is "suackea I 30 10193020 NL 3 e 1 64 :23 23% 34% 120". While the end is ok, the beginning is incorrect. The expected result is:

"Strackea III €0.10/€0.20 NL 6 6 1 €4 €23 23% 34% 120"

I have tried to do some transformation using imageMagick before tesseract to get an image with text written in black on a white background:

```
convert cropped.png -fuzz 28000 -fill black -opaque white cropped.png
convert cropped.png -fuzz 25000 -fill white -opaque rgb(118,118,118) cropped.png
```

The resulting image is [image]

[Download Image (right click -- save link as)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2e23.png)

```
tesseract cropped.png tess -psm 7
```

but the result is the same.

What transformation or other command line tool would you use to recognize the text correctly ?)

The font the text is written in is **Microsof Sans Serif**

Comment: I'd try to increase the image size first and use some transformation that just change color/saturation/contrast without any distortion in the characters

Comment: Do you mean by scaling the image ? Or by adding some whitespace ? What method do you recommend for changing the saturation/contrast ?

Comment: yes, I mean making it bigger. Even forcing imagemagik to do some interpolation to make it bigger, it's better than having it that small IMO. For contrast, take a look on these http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/color_mods/ -

Comment: Thanks for the link. Converting it to 5232*64 made it much better, and converting it to 10464x128 gives even better results.

Comment: nice to know that :-) I am pretty sure you'll find the sweet spot for this OCR quickly